# BASH param expansion from passed param

Tags: bash, shell, expansion

I am having an issue with shell param expansion in a /bin/bash script running as GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

```
# the cmdln args are
explore_asterisk_expansion.bash path/to/other/files file* my_files* log*

# the script assigns to internal variables as below
path=$1
shift
find_these=($@)

# I then loop through the find_these array as below
for f in $path/${find_these[@]} ; do
  echo f is $file
done
```

I get $path added only to the first argument passed.

For the cmd ln above, this means I get $path/file*, which is expanded successfully , & I get the expected 3 files echoed out, but the remaining args are echoed out exactly as passed i.e. my_files* log*, without $path and consequently the asterisk expansion fails.

Suggestions on how to get around this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prepend the path to each file before iterating through the array you can do.

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1
shift
find_these=( "$@" )

for f in "${find_these[@]/#/$path/}" ; do
  echo "f is $f"
done
```

I tested this on GNU bash 4.2.45(2) on OS X 10.9 and it works.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: But it doesn't expand the globs; it only prepends the path. You need to remove the quotes from `"${find_these[@]/#/$path}"` to achieve what the OP asks for. To the extent that achieving that is possible.

Comment: @rici I think the globs are already expanded when the script is called (well, that's what I understand since the OP calls the script with `explore_asterisk_expansion.bash path/to/other/files file* my_files* log*` at this point bash does the glob expansion, and the script `explore_asterisk_expansion.bash` has all the needed arguments expanded). No?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: OP wants to expand the `file*` in `path/to/other/files` so it is relying on `file*` *not* being expanded when the script is called (clearly a design weakness). From OP: "For the cmd ln above, this means I get $path/file*, which is expanded successfully , & I get the expected 3 files echoed out"

Comment: @rici: so the OP is really high on some psychotropic substance.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I wouldn't go that far :) It's doable except that it relies on the glob not matching anything in the CWD (or being quoted in the command line).

Comment: @rici Sure it's doable, `find` for example actually relies on wildcards. At this point I actually have no idea what the OP really wants. I'm out of here!

Answer (score 0):

Whether you only need to append the `path` to each of the rest of args, do the following:

```
for f in ${find_these[@]} ; do
  echo f is $path/$f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the variable `$file` is, but it looks like you might have meant to write `$f` instead of `$file`, because I see no other reason why you would be going through the loop with that variable.

```
for f in $path/${find_these[@]} ; do
  echo f is $f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to the directory before expanding the patterns (and you don't need to assign `$@` to a variable):

```
cd "$path"
for file in $@
...
```

Since you're doing the `cd` in a script, the outer environment stays in the same environment.

Example:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ cat test.sh 
path="$1"
shift
cd "$path"
for file in $@
do
    echo "Found file: $file"
done
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/a foo/abc
$ sh test.sh foo a*
Found file: a
Found file: abc
```